# synaptic package manager language problem

Tags: 12.04, gnome, synaptic, language-support

My synaptic package manager is showing weird behavior like "only synaptic manager is displayed in the chinese language" and "only it is shown in classic UI whereas every other application has theme applied on it"

Attached is the image for it.

[image]

can anyone tell solution to this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that happen when you run other applications with `root` privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Settings . you will find Language support . There select English and click at Apply system wide and try again .[image]

Comment: This solves my language problem. What about the look and feel of synapse package manager ?

Comment: open your appearance settings and click any other theme and apply it . after that again click at your original theme and then click at apply .